# Calculate 3dB bandwidth at a peak from magnitude-frequency plot

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to calculate the 3dB bandwidth from data containing **Power** in `dB` vs **Frequency** in `Hz`. For instance:

```
X = 
    2.9640   -5.0568
    2.9705   -4.5819
    2.9770   -4.1277
    2.9835   -3.7016
    2.9900   -3.3095
    2.9965   -2.9560
    3.0030   -2.6446
    3.0095   -2.3776
    3.0160   -2.1569
    3.0225   -1.9839
    3.0290   -1.8596
    3.0355   -1.7847
    3.0420   -1.7596
    3.0485   -1.7849
    3.0550   -1.8609
    3.0615   -1.9877
    3.0680   -2.1655
    3.0745   -2.3944
    3.0810   -2.6741
    3.0875   -3.0044
    3.0940   -3.3843
    3.1005   -3.8126
    3.1070   -4.2872
    3.1135   -4.8051
    3.1200   -5.3616
    3.1265   -5.9505
```

I get the peak I am interested in with `findpeaks` builtin function:

```
[pks, locs, w, p] = findpeaks(X.data(:,2), 'MinPeakProminence',3);
fstpeak = locs(1);
frequency = X(fstpeak,1);
peak_magnitude = X(fstpeak,2);
```

I can obviously make a for loop and look forward and backward from `fstpeak` until I get a value of magnitude below `peak_magnitude - 3`, and then interpolate if more precision is required.

It seems a pretty common operation, but I have tried to find a builtin matlab function with no success. Is there a builtin function I can use, or a faster approach to the custom for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem with doing this is going to be that your data is not monotonically increasing. Having said that, it does follow a nice curve - it rises to a maximum and then starts to decrease, and there is no noise. As such, you can split the curve in two shorter curves that are monotonically increasing/decreasing and use `interp1' to find the -3dB point.

```
frequency = X(:,1);
magnitude = (X:,2);
magnitude = magnitude - max(magnitude); % Normalise to maximum

indmax = find(magnitude == max(magnitude));

f1 = interp1(magnitude(1:indmax), frequency(1:indmax), -3);
f2 = interp1( magnitude(indmax:end), frequency(indmax:end), -3);
BW = f2 - f1;
```

This approach will fall down if you apply it to data that does not rise and then fall, or if you apply it to noisy data.

Comment: I have the width of the peak in w parameter, so I can extract the points that constitute the peak, and split given its position. It seems a good solution.